# java list creation methods difference

Tags: java

What's the difference between defining a arraylist like this:

```
List list = new LinkedList();
```

and like this?

```
LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
```

Comment: Well, for one thing neither is an arraylist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other answers have suggested, List is the interface, and LinkedList is the actual implementation type. If, for example, you later decided that you wanted to use an ArrayList, you could type:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
```

because ArrayList declares the interface List. The downside is that if you want to call any methods of an ArrayList/LinkedList/(Other classname that has methods that aren't in list) later that are not part of the List interface (this probably won't be an issue), you would have to check if it really was an ArrayList, etc. and cast it to those types. Like this:

```
ArrayList arrayList = (ArrayList) list;
```

*only after checking that it really is an ArrayList, otherwise you throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

The first one declares a List, and initializes it with a new LinkedList concrete implementation of the List interface. The rest of the code doesn't care about the concrete implementation. The only thing that matters is that it's a List. If you realize later that an ArrayList is more efficient, you just have to change the initialization.

The second one declares a LinkedList, and initializes it with a new LinkedList. The rest of the code knows that it's a LinkedList, and can use methods from LinkedList that are not in List. If you realize later that an ArrayList is more efficient, you might have to change the rest of the code.

The first one should generally preferred: use the most general type as possible, and code to interfaces rather than implementation.

Also, you should never use raw types, but always generic types:

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Comment: plus one for mentioning generics- I fight with 10 year old legacy code all day long, and that's the worst: Vector foo = new Vector();

Answer (score 1):

One uses the [interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) for the variable's type. The other uses [concrete class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) type.

In general, it's better to use an interface type for variable types, because they are more portable and produce less tightly [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29).

Answer (score 1):

This is called coding to interfaces. It has certain benefits. Based on your question, i think you are new to this language.

According to java world, following are some benefits

> Design: the methods of an object can be quickly specified and
>   published to all affected developers Development: the Java compiler
>   guarantees that all methods of the interface are implemented with the
>   correct signature and that all changes to the interface are
>   immediately visible to other developers Integration: there is the
>   ability to quickly connect classes or subsystems together, due to
>   their well-established interfaces Testing: interfaces help isolate
>   bugs because they limit the scope of a possible logic error to a given
>   subset of methods

This is a good place to start reading http://www.javaworld.com/jw-08-1999/jw-08-interfaces.html

Answer (score 0):

Both work. The difference is that `List` is an interface and `LinkedList` is an implementation. It is considered a better practice to use interfaces, because you can easily switch the implementation later.